# How to apply Jquery function to just one css class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an image slider and I want to add this fadeIn function to the text on each of my images , but it only works on my first image and the rest gets fadeIn so when the next slide comes the text is already visible

```
ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <img src="img/sister-religions.png" alt="">
            <figcaption class="slide-info" >
                <h1>TITLE </h1>
                <p>prompta, mea id quem odio. Quo an officiis vivendum consequat, usu ad stet offendit repudiare. Sonet option euismod in sea. Ad vis brute posidonium, in qui enim utamur recusabo.</p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/test1.png" alt="">
            <figcaption class="slide-info" >
                <h1>TITLE </h1>
                <p>prompta, mea id quem odio. Quo an officiis vivendum consequat, usu ad stet offendit repudiare. Sonet option euismod in sea. Ad vis brute posidonium, in qui enim utamur recusabo.</p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/test2.png" alt="">
            <figcaption class="slide-info" >
                <h1>TITLE </h1>
                <p>prompta, mea id quem odio. Quo an officiis vivendum consequat, usu ad stet offendit repudiare. Sonet option euismod in sea. Ad vis brute posidonium, in qui enim utamur recusabo.</p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
</ul>
```

here is the jquery code

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
         onSliderLoad: function(){

        $('.slide-info').fadeIn(3000);

      },
        onSlideAfter: function(){

        $('slide-info').fadeIn(3000);
      }
    });

 });
```

})(jQuery);

I only need it to apply to the current image figcaption not all of them ,

Answer (score 1):

`onSlideAfter` takes an argument

> Function argument is the current slide element (when transition completes).

So try

```
onSlideAfter: function(slide) {
    slide.find('.slide-info').fadeIn(3000);
}
```

I'd also remove the `onSliderLoad` handler.

Comment: onSlideAfter works but I dont get the effect on my first slide when the whole page and slider load

Answer (score 1):

BXSlider has a mode option you can pass to it that will make it fade without having to do any extra legwork.

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({ mode: 'fade'});
```

Comment: I am trying to fadein a container with bunch of text in for each image not fade the images

Comment: Change your list items to divs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488330/bxslider-wont-allow-html-text-within-slides

Comment: @CYBERSIX or are you saying you don't actually want the images to fade at all?

Comment: images slide or fade ,i dont care ,  when the imageslider is loaded , i want to fadein some text , it work with the code Phil gave me but not on the first image , when I go to next image I have the fadein effect but not when the image slider first loaded

Comment: Check out the link I pasted above, BXSlider can fade your html and images in and out but you'll need to change your lists to divs.

Comment: the link you sent me goes to this jsfiddle [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/E8NgR/) and it s not what I am after, take a look at this [WOWSLIDER](http://wowslider.com/wordpress-gallery-sky-blur-demo.html), see how text appears , that is what i am trying to do

Comment: @CYBERSIX http://jsfiddle.net/E8NgR/77/ you just have to add mode: 'fade', if you want the same effect as WOW slider then why dont you use that instead? You can also just add a CSS transition onto the text if you want.

Comment: Adding the mode:'fade will fade the whole image and text , all i want is to onload add the fade effect , it s working when i change the slide but not on load , when i put any function in the onSliderLoad: , it effects all my images , i need a way to just target the current image on load that is it , and i dont want to use wow slider