# bxSlider - placing divs inside the slider + text and background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I am using bxSlider.Basically the slider's structure is the following:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="img_1.png" alt="First">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="img_2.png" alt="Second">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img_3.png" alt="Third">
    </li>
</ul>
```

The slider works perfectly like that. The problem is that there are only images showing.If I add the code below between my `<li></li>`

```
 <div> 
        <h2> Hello World! </h2> 
 </div>
```

That goes below or above the image,  not fitting into slider.
Should I use bxslider with divs instead , and placing the image as a background? like
HTML:

```
<div class="bxslider">
   <div class="firstHolder">
      <div class="firstSection">
         <h2> Hello world</h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor as simet ... </p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .firstHolder{
     background-image:url(../img/img_1.png);
     background-size:cover;
  }
```

But in that case , my background-image is not showing in full height , until I do not fill the container with enough text.So I want to achieve something like this
[image]. So It is a bit confusing by now but, I want you to help me, should I use divs + background image to apply a text and some button on my slider picture , or there's another way using `ul` and `li` structure , thanks.

Comment: providing a fiddle would be much better

Comment: ok sec, I`ll try , my question is a bit complicated lol.

Comment: @Sachin brah I can't adjust the jsfiddle , because there are a lot stuffs. Would you like to upload my issue on github and just clone it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out the first bit of code on my machine and it works out fine.

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});

</script>
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="img1.png" alt="First">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="img2.png" alt="Second">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img3.png" alt="Third">
      <div>
      <h2>This is a test</h2>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I then tried the second

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});

</script>

<div class="bxslider">
   <div class="firstHolder">
      <div class="firstSection">
         <h2> Hello world</h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor as simet ... </p>
      </div>
   </div>

<style>

.firstHolder{
     background-image:url(img1.png);
     background-size:cover;
  }
</style>
```

And that worked fine too so unless i didn't understand your question. I have no clue. I think there might be a problem with the script or img srcs or you haven't shown enough code to properly debug.

Comment: No , bro. when I set the background img it doesn't appear in full height... if I set padding-top and padding-bottom with % it works , but when I resize the view-port , it sucks....  I mean how to make it full height as background img for the slider?

Comment: I want to make something like the picture I've showed, adding text + button on the full height img slider.

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev If you mean full screen by full height then try this article out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789254/making-an-element-fill-the-entire-height-of-browser-viewport-using-jquery) otherwise I will try playing with the code to find the issue

Comment: After searching stack overflow here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488330/bxslider-wont-allow-html-text-within-slides